# Enable dark mode for specific applications or windows - Windows 10 Build 1903

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1903

How do i enable dark mode for some specific apps rather than setting `default app mode` as dark. For example, i want to enable dark mode only for CMD.

[image: Dark Mode enabled CMD]

Comment: This is not possible - it's either all or none.